# Example of a markov chain with transient and recurrent states

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

As the title says, I can't come up with an example of a markov chain with all possible states (transient, positive recurrent and null recurrent). I know that the state space must be infinite, otherwise all recurrent classes are positive recurrent. Any suggestions?

Comment: you can have a markov chain that goes from $i$ to $i+1$ with probability $p$ and to $0$ with probability $1-p$

Answer (score 1):

Consider a state space $\mathcal S=\{0\}\cup \{\delta\}\cup A\cup B$, where $A=\{a_1,a_2,\ldots\}$ and $B=\{b_1,b_2,\ldots\}$, and transition probabilities
$$ 
P_{ij} = 
\begin{cases}
\frac13,& i=0, j\in\{\delta, a_1,b_1\}\\
1,& i = j = \delta\\
\frac13,& i=j=a_1\\
\frac23,& i=a_n, j=a_{n+1}\\
\frac13,& i=a_{n+1}, j=a_n\\
\frac23,& i=j=b_1\\
\frac13,& i=b_n, j=b_{n+1}\\
\frac23,& i=b_{n+1}, j=b_n.\\
\end{cases}
$$
Then $0$ is transient, $\delta$ is absorbing, $A$ is null recurrent, and $B$ is positive recurrent. (Draw the transition diagram.)